# Jquery - Fullcalendar (v1.6.4) - Some events does not SHOW end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, events, fullcalendar

I'm using Jquery Fullcalendar (v1.6.4) in one of my projects. Actually I have the following starting setup for the calendar object:

```
$j('#maincal').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: '',
                        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                columnFormat: {
                        week: 'ddd dd/MM',
                        day: 'dddd dd/MM/yyyy'
                },
                defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                minTime: 0,
                maxTime: 24,
                axisFormat: 'H:mm',
                timeFormat: { agenda: 'HH:mm{ - dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}', },
                firstDay: 1,
                firstHour: 8,
                ignoreTimezone: false,
                allDaySlot: false,
                slotMinutes: 5,
                editable: false,
                theme: false,
                lazyFetching: true,
                handleWindowResize: true
});
```

my event array has elements like this one:

```
allDay: false
backgroundColor: "#FFC0FF"
borderColor: "#FF00FF"
editable: false
end: "2014-03-26T11:02:34+01:00"
id: "14"
start: "2014-03-26T11:00:30+01:00"
textColor: "#1e1e1e"
title: "This event has no end date, why?"
```

My problem is that even if the element has an end date (end: "2014-03-26T11:02:34+01:00") when it is render in the calendar it shows up like the picture below.

[image: damn end date]

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can i fix it?
Thanks in advance, Best A.

EDIT: [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bQXYp/107/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't say exactly with these details. But I have a doubt about your data set.

your end date is   `end: "2014-03-26T11:02:34+01:00"`

your start date is `start: "2014-03-26T11:00:30+01:00"`

if you can see the event duration is nearly **2mins**.

Now take a look at the picture. your event time step gap is **5mins**. So it can't show you the **2mis** duration in a clear manner. But yet I can see some little deviation. (`I think you are doing it correct , and you have got the correct result`).

I think here your problem is your event duration is too small so you can't see a big difference in the display. try event with a big duration. I think you did it correctly.